# Why does not work ng-click in controller Angular JS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use Jquery plugin bootstrapCheckboxes. So, these checkboxes I create inside Angular JS function:

```
$scope.createDropDownList = function (element, data, title) {
    $(element).dropdownCheckbox({
        data: data,
        autosearch: true,
        hideHeader: false,
        showNbSelected: true,
        templateButton: '<a class="dropdown-checkbox-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span>' + title + '</span> <span class="dropdown-checkbox-nbselected"></span><b class="caret"></b></button>'
    });
}
```

It works and dropdown list appears on page with checkboxes -one of them:

```
<input type="checkbox" required="" value="1" ng-click="selectType(1, $event)">
```

You can see event `ng-click(selectType(1, $event))`.

At Angular JS I have this method:

```
$scope.function = selectType(){
   alert('done');
}
```

But after click I dont get alert message and other errors in console.
What may cause?

Comment: why you used jquery inside angular controller?

Comment: your click function, is that a typo or you seriously have done that mistake in the function definition ?

Comment: `$scope.function = selectType()` I think you have turned these 2 around, it must be `$scope.selectType = function()`

Comment: Sorry I made mistake on post, there over  `$scope.selectType = function()`

Answer (score 1):

The html you see `<input type="checkbox" required="" value="1" ng-click="selectType(1, $event)">` is not compiled against the angular scope, it is generated (somehow) by the jQuery plugin, so the angular is not aware that you placed a `ng-click` on the element, therefore nothing happens when you click it. If a fiddle will be provided, I'll try to provide an working solution.

Comment: I have connected Angular JS library: http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/ But this gives me errors: `_ is not defined at link.$scope.isChecked` `_ is not defined
    at link.$scope.getButtonText`

Comment: The library has several dependencies, one of them is lodash.js (which is a kind of wrapper over underscorejs). I recommend to you to check the bower file which lists all the required libs (https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/bower.json) and make sure you have the dependencies included in your project.

Answer (score 0):

That is not right method to define click event using Angular.js.

It is something like below
In your js file write the below function.

```
function your_controller_name($scope){
   $scope.selectType=function(){
       alert("done").
     }
}
```

Link this js file in your html page and your_controller_name stand for what you have set in ng-controller.